# Ionic ion-list vs .list

Tags: ionic-framework

In Ionic, we can do something like this for the list view:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item href="#">
        Butterfinger
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And also like this:

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item" href="#">
        Butterfinger
    </a>
</div>
```

These 2 basically output the same layout. What is the difference between these 2? Will do it with the `div` method will result in better performance? If so, then why `ion-list`?

Comment: Ionic is a framework to generate the HTML. You can use the second one, but you will miss some features of Ionic built in.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any differences from CSS styling point of view (except some color styling on child text) between using `<ion-list>` and `<div class="list">` because `<ion-list>` is a directive and it will render `<div class="list">` inside it. If you inspect element you will see this 
(rendered html picked from browser element inspection)

```
<ion-list>
 <div class="list">
    <ion-item href="#" class="item item-complex">
     <a class="item-content" ng-href="#" href="#">
        Butterfinger
     </a>
    </ion-item>
 </div>
</ion-list>
```

As you can see in above code ion-list generate a div with list class.
Plus see the [source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/list.js#L12-L17) of `ion-list` it will make things more clearer. I am just sharing a line from source code to show what template this directive render

```
var listEl = jqLite('<div class="list">')
```

There will be no performance difference between both, but i will suggest you to  use `<div class="list">` if you do not want to use apis of `ion-list` and want to have more control over element while doing customization.
As far as your question "why `ion-list`" is concerned, the directive gives you access to many options in the API. The API methods listed in the bottom of the docs pages (like [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/) for example) gives you a sense of what the directive allows you to do, instead of just using the CSS associated with the class.
Quoting from documentation

> However, using the ionList and ionItem directives make it easy to
>   support various interaction modes such as swipe to edit, drag to
>   reorder, and removing items.

**Conclusion**: So it totaly depends upon your requirement, whether to use directive or use simple class on div.

Comment: Also note, that if you include the HTML yourselve `<div class="list">` instead of the directive `<ion-list>` and anything would change in this directive / HTML markup the change won't be affected if you use the HTML version.